# При нажатии на первый блок, происходит сбой

Tags: javascript, jquery

При нажатии на `div` всплывает модальное окно,при нажатии на 1 элемент,оно открывается и тут же скрывается.Где косяк?

```
<div  data-dialog="somedialog" class="trigger" >1</div><br>
<div  data-dialog="somedialog" class="trigger" >2</div><br>
<div  data-dialog="somedialog" class="trigger" >3</div><br>
<div  data-dialog="somedialog" class="trigger" >4</div><br>
<div  data-dialog="somedialog" class="trigger" >5</div><br>

<div id="somedialog" class="dialog">
                    <div class="dialog__overlay"></div>
                    <div class="dialog__content">
                        Диалоговое окно<div><button class="action" data-dialog-close>Close</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

window.dlgtrigger = document.querySelector('[data-dialog]'),
  window.somedialog = document.getElementById(window.dlgtrigger.getAttribute('data-dialog')),
  window.dlg = new DialogFx(window.somedialog);

window.dlgtrigger.addEventListener('click', window.dlg.toggle.bind(window.dlg));

$(".trigger").click(function() {

  dlg.toggle.bind(dlg)();


});
```

Все тут http://jsfiddle.net/ed0coLdw/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут банальная невнимательность.

Вот вы привязали действие по клику в первый раз:

```
window.dlgtrigger.addEventListener('click', window.dlg.toggle.bind(window.dlg));
```

Вот вы привязали действие по клику во второй раз:

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
  dlg.toggle.bind(dlg)();
});
```

В итоге по одному клику действие срабатывает дважды, а поскольку стоит `toggle`,  то эффект получается равным щелчку `вкл/выкл`.

Оставьте один обработчик события или исправьте логику обработки.

Comment: Спасибо,выручили,да уж ну и ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div  data-dialog="somedialog" class="trigger" >1</div><br>
<div  data-dialog="somedialog" class="trigger" >2</div><br>
<div  data-dialog="somedialog" class="trigger" >3</div><br>
<div  data-dialog="somedialog" class="trigger" >4</div><br>
<div  data-dialog="somedialog" class="trigger" >5</div><br>
<div id="somedialog" class="dialog">
    <div class="dialog__overlay"></div>
    <div class="dialog__content">
        <p>Диалоговое окно</p>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="dialog-close-btn action" data-dialog-close>Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


(function(){
    var $dialogTemplate;

    $(function(){
        $dialogTemplate = $('.dialog').detach();
    });

    var showDialog = function() {
        var $dialog = $dialogTemplate.clone();
        $(document.body).append($dialog);
    };

    var removeDialog = function() {
        $('.dialog').remove();
    };

    $(document).on('click', '.trigger', showDialog);
    $(document).on('click', '.dialog-close-btn', removeDialog);
})();
```

Это Вам реально упростит задачу.

Просто записывайте в буфер этот элемент и потом при необходимости добавляйте его в DOM и удаляйте когда закрываете его.